New Dataframe columns from column of arrays
I have this Dataframe :
+---------+
|     data|
+---------+
|[a, b, c]|
|[d, e, f]|
|[g, h, i]|
+---------+

And a list of column name ["first col", "second col", "third col"]
I want to create new columns to produce the following dataframe :
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  first col| second col| third col|
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|          a|          b|         c|
|          d|          e|         f|
|          g|          h|         i|
+-----------+-----------+----------+

I'm scratching my head on how to do that, what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Can you be more precise: Are you using pyspark? Did you try some code and get specific errors?

Wouldn't simple element_at work for some reason? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#map-functions

Untested code but the idea is to just use getItem() to access the ith element of the data column which in your case is a list, and store them in new columns created with withColumn

df = spark.createDataFrame([(['a', 'b', 'c'],), (['d', 'e', 'f'],), (['g', 'h', 'i'],)], ['data'])
col_names = ['first col', 'second col', 'third col']

for i, name in enumerate(col_names):
    df = df.withColumn(name, col('data').getItem(i))

df = df.drop('data')


